# How to set pie chart each slice height using Zoomcharts

Tags: javascript, zoomcharts

i need to set each slice height based on value which am passing. I need to plot a pie chart like this [Pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcND9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cut-out distance to simulate similar effect. Setting: https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/pie-chart/api-reference/settings/slice/style.html#doc_cutoutDistance